# ORDER BY clause in SQL Server 

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, sql-order-by

Recently I was working one of the select query, wherein I wanted to sort the rows based on latest date and time which are stored in different columns. The requirement by client was that the time will be custom, so I cannot use the `DateTime` together.

Now I have 2 questions:

1. It was not sorting until I made the changes in order by clause. my original order by clause was:

   ```
   ORDER BY PublishDate, PublishTime DESC
   ```

   The above query was working fine, but was only sorting the `PublishDate`, and doing nothing with `PublishTime`, I understand that it will primarily sort on the basis of `PublishDate`, and would give second preference to `PublishTime`, but with the above query it wasn't giving any preference to `PublishTime`, but when I changed the order by clause to below it worked fine:

   ```
   ORDER BY PublishDate DESC, PublishTime DESC
   ```

   Can anyone tell me what's the difference between the two queries? Why don't both give primary preference to `PublishDate` and secondary to `PublishTime`?
2. Is it possible to append the custom time to a `DateTime` column, I mean say for example if users added a row on `31 March 2012`, and entered `4:00PM`, is it possible to add the custom time to the the current date retrieved using `GETDATE()`

Comment: Which data types are you using for these columns?

Comment: Datetime columns already have the time inside them.  Did you make PublishDate a Date, or a DateTime?
Date: select publishDate + ' ' + publishTime
DateTime: select cast(cast(publishDate as Date) as varchar) + ' ' + publishTime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The former clause was sorting by `PublishDate ASC` (the default direction).

In this example data set:

```
PublishDate    PublishTime
1/1/2012       01:00
12/1/2011      03:00
1/1/2012       03:00
1/1/2012       01:30
1/3/2012       01:30
1/5/2012       01:30
```

The first clause would produce:

```
PublishDate    PublishTime
12/1/2011      03:00
1/1/2012       03:00
1/1/2012       01:30
1/1/2012       01:00
1/3/2012       01:30
1/5/2012       01:30
```

While the second clause would produce:

```
PublishDate    PublishTime
1/5/2012       01:30
1/3/2012       01:30
1/1/2012       03:00
1/1/2012       01:30
1/1/2012       01:00
12/1/2011      03:00
```

Answer (score 5):

The default sort in an order by clause is ASC.  So if you don't specify, SQL Server sticks in ASC.  So you're really comparing

```
Order By PublishDate ASC, PublishTime DESC
```

to

```
Order By PublishDate DESC, PublishTime DESC
```

That's why the second one is giving you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As the others mentioned, The default sort for order by is ASC.

For your second question, try this:

```
declare @newDateTime as datetime
declare @userTime as time
set @userTime = '4:00PM'
select @newDateTime = 
CONVERT(varchar(10), getDate(), 101) +' '+ convert(varchar(8), @userTime,108)

select @newDateTime --current date + user time entry
```